# Environment.OSVersion in PowerShell vs PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-ise

Why is it that I see 2 different versions of my OS from PowerShell and PowerShell ISE?

The OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter Evaluation

PowerShell: version 4.0

**PowerShell**

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      3      9600   0
```

**PowerShell ISE**

```
PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      2      9200   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Windows 8.1 / Server 2012 the GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) return the data for Windows 8 (6.2 Build 9200) if the application doesn't contain the supportedOS Id for Windows 8.1.

Looks like the GUI doesn't include this entry.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 is 6.2 version too. Build ?

Comment: @Kiquenet yes, 2012 = 6.2 and 2012R2 = 6.3

Comment: How difference **Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8** and How difference **Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet which programming language do you use?

Comment: C# .NET and Powershell

Comment: @Kiquenet make sure that the supportedOS Id entry is added to the app.config and the calls should be fine. Now use http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getversionex and look for the wProductType value. Win8 = VER_NT_WORKSTATION